# How to switch the point to previous line after a } was input?

Tags: emacs, elisp, cc-mode

I am working with emacs24 with cc-mode, I want to know how to make my emacs more "clever". After I type a }, it will auto insert a new line and indent as excepted. I want to know how to switch the point to previous line.
For example, when i define a function, Now my emacs behavior is:

```
void f()
{
}
//point
```

"//point" is the position of cursor after } was input.
But i want is this:

```
void f()
{
    //point
}
```

I hope the position of cursor can switch to previous line and indent automatically.
I know emacs can do this, but I don't know how to do it, who can help me?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are after these.. `C-M-u`, `C-M-d`, `C-M-f` and `C-M-b`

Practice a bit... They are kind of global and they do behave contextually in almost all modes..

UPDATE:

ohh.. It seems you want to place the cursor automatically.. actually in more general Emacs will help you not to type `}` at all. I mean emacs can insert closing paran automatically.

There is inbuilt one
electric pair mode

third party 
autopair.el

Answer (score 0):

I don't trust anything electric, so I wrote this function.

```
(defconst insert-logical-brackets-logical-bracket-begin "{")
(defconst insert-logical-brackets-logical-bracket-end "}")
(defconst insert-logical-brackets-default-style 0)
(make-variable-buffer-local 'logical-bracket-begin)
(make-variable-buffer-local 'logical-bracket-end)
(make-variable-buffer-local 'insert-logical-brackets-default-style)
(defun insert-logical-brackets(&optional style)
  "If STYLE = 0(default, according to `insert-logical-brackets-default-style' value), make a newline before opening bracket, if line is not empty. Make a newline after closing bracket, if there is something after this bracket. Make two newlines in the middle.
If STYLE = 1, don't make newlines before opening a bracket(one of c styles).
If STYLE = 2, don't make newlines before opening and after closing bracket.
If STYLE = 3, allways make all newlines.
If STYLE is not nil, don't make newlines between brackets(still makes before/after lines)."
  (interactive "P")
  (when (eq style nil)
    (setq style insert-logical-brackets-default-style))
  (funcall indent-line-function)
  (unless (or (eq 1 style) (eq 2 style))
    (when (or (/= (point) (save-excursion (back-to-indentation) (point))) (eq 3 style))
      (newline)
      (funcall indent-line-function)))
  (unless (and (integerp style) (= 2 style))
    (when (or (not (looking-at "\n")) (eq 3 style))
      (newline)
      (funcall indent-line-function)
      (forward-line -1)
      (goto-char (point-at-eol))))
  (insert logical-bracket-begin)
  (funcall indent-line-function)
  (let ((return-point (point)))
    (when (or (not style) (or (eq 0 style) (eq 1 style) (eq 2 style) (eq 3 style)))
      (newline)
      (funcall indent-line-function)
      (setq return-point (point))
      (newline))
    (insert logical-bracket-end)
    (funcall indent-line-function)
    (goto-char return-point)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at template systems like yasnippet: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryTemplates

Answer (score 0):

[auto-indent-mode](https://github.com/mlf176f2/auto-indent-mode.el) maybe what you want!